# NordVPN does not install in Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS

Tags: software-installation

Having bought NordVPN and installed on one Windows PC (easy) and on one running Elementary OS Juno (difficult) I am now finding that nothing works to get it installed on a machine running Ubuntu.  The NordVPN installation instructions are useless and help there is nonexistent.  I tried the terminal commands that work in Elementary, as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

It fails after the second command on which it seems only to be updating Ubuntu.
I tried the final installation command: `sudo apt-get install nordvpn` and it returned `E: unable to locate package VPN`.

Is there a better VPN for Linux, preferably one with a GUI?

Comment: You might have better luck with this guide instead https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/ About half-way down are instructions on using the built-in GUI. It doesn't mention it but you will still need to install OpenVPN separately, use the following commands if needed: `sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc`

Comment: Thank you.  I did get it working via the shell method, which I thought pretty cumbersome. An attempt to connect via network manager failed.  As I was working with a new installation of Ubuntu I wiped the entire drive and started again.  I tried and failed to get it to work via network manager as VPN OFF never even appeared in the network selection box.  I installed it again using the 4 steps on the Nordvpn website and this time it worked, but I still have to switch it on using Terminal and still cannot get a connection via Network Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Manually add the repository by going to the software & updates app, then click on Other Software and add either of the following lines depending on your system architecture:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
deb [arch=i386 ] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

Open your terminal and run:

```bsh
$ sudo apt update
```

You may most likely encounter a GPG error of NO_PUBKEY, copy the following code to the terminal and run:

```bsh
sudo wget https://repo.nordvpn.com/gpg/nordvpn_public.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

This would fix the error.

Finally, run:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install nordvpn
```

Tada!

You can also check other answers here: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/1230982/1068121

Comment: @Pilot6 Just edited my answer to include necessary details to solve the problem.

Comment: That's good. I am removing my review comment. But I can't remove the delete vote. Now it won't attract any more votes. Downvote was not mine.