# E: Unable to locate package nordvpn

Tags: apt, dpkg, vpn, openvpn

I tried installing nordvpn on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 but keeps showing me the above error message. I've tried every possible option on the internet from forums to forums, still nothing.
I used the general method of downloading the repository package and installed it using these:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

After all these commands, it still ends up showing the same error message. I don't know what else to do.

I'm helpless at the moment.

Comment: If you downloaded it then `sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb` is enough to install it. What does `dpkg -l | grep -i "nordvpn"` show?

Comment: @Raffa It keeps showing “E: Unable to locate package nordvpn”

Comment: Showing what??? run only `dpkg -l | grep -i "nordvpn"` and add the output to your question

Comment: @Raffa After running `dpkg -l | grep -i "nordvpn"`, the ouput was:

```code
ii  nordvpn-release                            1.0.0                                      all          Package to install NordVPN GPG key and APT repo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download the `nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb` file from the [official website](https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/).
Then install `nordvpn-release` by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ./{/path/to/}nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

After `nordvpn-release` installs, update your system (make sure to update AND upgrade):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

You should be able to install `nordvpn` sucessfully:

```
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

Alternatively, you can add the repository and then update your system:

```
sudo wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

**If the issue still persists**, manually add the repository to the `apt` sources list:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo nano nordvpn.list
```

Then add the following lines to the file (ONLY do this if the file is empty or there is text that is commented out):

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
deb [arch=i386 ] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

Then update the system:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If you get an error like `Target Packages ... is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:2`, then delete one of the two lines and repeat the last step. If you you're unsure which line to use, check `uname -m`.

You should then be able to install `nordvpn`:

```
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

If you get the GPG error of `NO_PUBKEY`, then copy the following command into terminal:

```
sudo wget https://repo.nordvpn.com/gpg/nordvpn_public.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Tried it but still the same error message.

Comment: @FOBABS Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you are running

Comment: Included the versions in the summary section

Comment: @FOBABS I edited my answer to include another method to add the repository. Can you try that and report back on whether it works or not?

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: @FOBABS Post `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list`

Comment: This is the message that displays: ```# # NordVPN releases, stable #```

Comment: @FOBABS I added how to manually add the repositories to the nordvpn.list file in my answer. Please try that and see if it if works

Comment: What I did was going directly to software & updates app and add this there: `deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main` then `sudo apt update`. It then displayed GPG error of NO_PUBKEY. I then copied this command to my terminal `sudo wget https://repo.nordvpn.com/gpg/nordvpn_public.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -` from [NordVPN Support](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm) which fixed the key ish then finally run `sudo apt install nordvpn` and it installed.

Comment: @FOBABS Glad that your issue was resolved!

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Unfortunately none of that worked for Pop!.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with Ubuntu 22.04. The suggestion above by FOBABS worked. Using the software and updates app,manually add `deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main` then do `sudo apt install nordvpn`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the public key wasn't available, which lead to terminal not being able to locate install nordvpn package or whatever. Somehow I stumbled across `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 931FF8E79F0876134EDDBDCCA87FF9DF48BF1C90`
ran that then installed, and everything was a-o-k.

Answer (score 0):

Download NordVPN public key and turn it into a GPG key

```
curl https://repo.nordvpn.com/gpg/nordvpn_public.asc > nordvpn-keyring.asc
sudo gpg --output=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nordvpn-keyring.gpg --dearmor nordvpn-keyring.asc
rm nordvpn-keyring.asc
```

Add NordVPN as a trusted repository

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list
```

Update your package database and install NordVPN

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install nordvpn --yes
```